# jQuery function doesn't respond to ".click" until I move the cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I have a website with a simple CSS style switcher. I use the following code for the function that handles clicking the two theme buttons, initiating the switch from dark to light and vice versa:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $(".light").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href", "css/lightHome.css");
        $(".light").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(".dark").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled")

    })
    $(".dark").click(function(){
        $("link").attr("href", "css/home.css");
        $(".dark").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(".light").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled")
    })
});
</script>
```

Everything about it operates exactly as I want, except the fact that when I click the button, nothing happens. But the second I shift the cursor position after the click, then the switch occurs. I don't have the best jQuery grasp, so I am hoping it is a simple lack of understanding regarding the DOM processes. Possibly having to do with the lack of "on ready"?

I've tried clicking and waiting several minutes, and nothing happens until I move the cursor.

The website:

http://watsoncn.info

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome, FF, and IE. What browser do you use?

Comment: For me, the first time I tried it - it happened as you described. But from then onwards, it was fine? Even after refreshing the page.

Comment: How long have you waited after the click? Might take a while on your system / browser.

Comment: I can still see the bug. Using Chrome latest in win 7.

Comment: As requested, I just waited (120 seconds) with no change, until I moved my cursor. I'm running up to date chrome on a 2 month old mac pro.

Comment: Try using .on("click")?

Comment: The function is responding correctly, if you open the network panel you will see that the css is loaded without any delay, but yes, the styles are applied with a delay, as you described.

Comment: Also instead of resetting the complete CSS file, I would do something in these lines. Add a parent wrapper class and toggle that on the `body tag` which would give you the specific theme.

Comment: I feel like the problem is that you're retrieving the CSS file fine and it is does get applied as soon as you click, but you need a screen refresh to update it? Try toggling the display of the body to `display:none` and back to `display:block` to force a refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of completely switching the CSS file, an alternative solution would be to have a single CSS file with both your styles and then prefixing all your selectors with `.theme.dark` or `.theme.light`;

This would be pretty easy to do with nesting in LESS or SASS if you're using them (if you're not, you really should consider it. I can't imagine writing CSS without a preprocessor now), but might be cumbersome in pure CSS.

CSS:

```
.theme.dark <rest of selectors> {
    //CSS
}

.theme.light <rest of selectors> {
    //CSS
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="theme">
```

and then code that runs on button clicks would be

```
$('body').addClass('dark')
$('body').removeClass('light')
```

and

```
$('body').addClass('light')
$('body').removeClass('dark')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function toggleCss(file, index) {
    var oldFile = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(index);
    var newFile = document.createElement("link");
    newFile.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newFile.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newFile.setAttribute("href", file);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newFile, oldFile);
}

$(".dark").on("click", function() {
    toggleCss("css/lightHome.css");
    $(".dark").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".light").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$(".light").on("click", function() {
    toggleCss("css/home.css");
    $(".light").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".dark").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add use not a JavaScript, but the "checkbox trick". The checkbox handler set to display none, then style the main style, and on :checked style the handler like it clicked.
With this you can not use JavaScript but make it 100% working without any bugs, if you did everything right!

You can find the DevTips channel on YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/user/DevTipsForDesigners

on his channel you can find the tutorial how to do that!